# Some very basic pde's I can't solve

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I encountered the following system of pde's:

I have two functions, $f(x,y),g(x,y)$, both of which are functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$ (I don't really care).

These functions satisfy the PDE's:

$\dfrac{df}{dx} +g(x,y)\cdot A_1(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot A_2(x,y) = 0$

$\dfrac{df}{dy} +g(x,y)\cdot A_3(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot A_4(x,y) = 0$

$\dfrac{dg}{dx} +g(x,y)\cdot B_1(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot B_2(x,y) = 0$

$\dfrac{dg}{dy} +g(x,y)\cdot B_3(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot B_4(x,y) = 0$

where $A_1,...,B_4$ are all "nice" functions of $x$ and $y$.

I wonder if there is any systematic technique which allows one to find $f$ and $g$ based on these equations. I have a hunch that there should be some general technique involving integration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean partial derivative you need to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{df}{dx}$. One can try calculate $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ from both of first two equations, and $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial y}$ from both of last two equations. Then one can make them equal and use all the equations to get something like $C_1 f+C_2 g=0$, $C_3 f+C_4 g=0$, where $C_i$ depend on $A_i$ and $B_i$. If $A_i$ and $B_i$ do not meet special requirement, the solution is $f=g=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} +g(x,y)\cdot A_1(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot A_2(x,y) = 0
\quad\implies
g=-\frac{1}{A_1}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{A_2}{A_1}f$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} +g(x,y)\cdot A_3(x,y) + f(x,y)\cdot A_4(x,y) = 0
\quad\implies
g=-\frac{1}{A_3}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{A_4}{A_3}f$

$-\frac{1}{A_1}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{A_2}{A_1}f=-\frac{1}{A_3}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{A_4}{A_3}f$

$$A_3(x,y)\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} -A_1(x,y)\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=  \big(A_1(x,y)A_4(x,y)- A_2(x,y) A_3(x,y)\big)f(x,y)$$

$A_5(x,y)=A_1(x,y)A_4(x,y)- A_2(x,y) A_3(x,y)$

$$\boxed{A_3(x,y)\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} -A_1(x,y)\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=  A_5(x,y)f(x,y)}$$

This is a first order linear PDE to be solved for $f(x,y)$. They are infinity many solutions until not boundary condition is specified. This is for equations 1 and 2 alone (without equations 3 and 4).

Then $g(x,y)=-\frac{1}{A_3(x,y)}\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{A_4(x,y)}{A_3(x,y)}f(x,y)$

Thus the solutions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are found only using the two first equations.

One can proceed in the same manner with equations 3 and 4, leading to solutions $g(x,y)$ and then $f(x,y)$. In the general case they will be different from the ones found above. The system of four equations is overdetermined.

Execept in particular cases of particular functions (i.e. not indepedent but related one to others)  $A_1(x,y), A_2(x,y), A_3(x,y),A_4(x,y), B_1(x,y), B_2(x,y),B_3(x,y), B_4(x,y)$ there will be no common solution other than $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ for equations 1,2,3 and 4 together.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the second line, $-df/dx$ should be $-df/dy$.

Comment: @ kindasorta : Sure !  An obvious typo repeated all along. Now corrected. Thank you very much.